# Strange date in start and end parameter Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

I'm using plugin [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io). Using events parameter to fetch data from webservice according with [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed)  .
I would have expected the dates sent to the web service to match the calendar view (start and end month) but not.
In fact, with the monthly view on 10 December 2020, the following dates are sent to the webservice: http://localhost:49988/Webservice/Calendar.asmx/GetCalendarDate?start=2020-11-30&end=2021-01-11&_=1607522494682
If I then scroll through the calendar in the previous months, the dates are even stranger. If I then scroll through the calendar in the previous months, the dates are even stranger: 26 October 2020 and 7 December 2020.
Why?
How I can send current view limit: example 01 December 2020 to 31 December 2020?

Comment: To ensure all combinations of first-day-of-week to last-day-of-week can fit within a calendar, it needs to display 6 weeks - so every month is shown with 6 weeks and is always the same 6x7 grid rather than some months shown with 4, 5 or 6 (partial) weeks.   2020-11-30 -> 2021-01-10 is 6 weeks, so guessing "end=" would be non-inclusive to give 2021-01-11.  If you're on windows 10, slick the time/date in the taskbar (if shown) and scroll through the months.

Comment: "the calendar view (start and end month)" ...look carefully at the default month view on any fullCalendar demo. Does it actually begin and end with the first and last day of the month, or is there some overlap? You'll notice that the dates sent to the webservice match the first and last days visible in the view, not the first and last days of the month.